# In-App Purchasing?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, in-app-purchase

In my project I want to include a store feature without having to setup a server where the user downloads it from as a document. I want to use a method where I include all the store bought features into my app already, but they won't be able to use them unless they pay for the specific feature. So basically, I'm saying that I want the user to trigger a BOOLEAN to YES once they pay to allow the button to be used, rather than downloading it from a URL or a server. My store features are different sounds in a soundboard. Thanks

Comment: How do I make the user switch the Boolean to YES I don't want to have to create a separate provisioning profile, server, id, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the boolean setting in [NSUserDefaults](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/).

Comment: Ok, so I add in my content, set it to hidden, then setup the boolean to make the content.hidden = NO; ?

Comment: Right, bundle the content with the app, and set a property in NSUserDefaults, call it content_hidden, to YES. In the UI, check that property and don't show the extra content unless it's NO. When the user buys the content, set it to NO.

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` is not secure.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using [MKStoreKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit). It's `isFeaturePurchased` will return a BOOL telling you if the user has purchased something. It handles all the gritty StoreKit functionality and almost everything when dealing with in app purchases.